# How to find Partition of unity in $ \mathbb{S}^n$ with only $2$ functions

Tags: general-topology, integer-partitions, smooth-manifolds

How  to find Partition of unity in $\mathbb{S}^n$ with only  $2$ functions?

Comment: Parameterize your partition by one of the coordinates. Then you just need a partition of unity on $[-1, 1]$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**
Do this on $S^1=\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ first and then modify (replacing $x$ with $\|x\|$) adapt to $S^n$. I assume you know the standard construction of bump functions.